org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query when SQL is inserted
I use below code to execute native query:
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Users{

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "cons_seq", sequenceName = "cons_seq", allocationSize = 100)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cons_seq")
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String created_by;
}

Repository:
@Repository
public interface ProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Long> {

  @Query(value = """
                    INSERT INTO users (id, created_by)
                    VALUES (nextval('cons_seq'), :createdBy)
            """, nativeQuery = true)
  void create(@Param("createdBy") String createdBy);
}

.......

public void create(final Profile profile) {
    profileRepository.create("test);
}

I get error:

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.

Record is added into database but I get the error. Do you know how I can fix this issue?
Gradle file:
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-loadbalancer'
    implementation 'org.springframework.retry:spring-retry'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.13.0'
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.17.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20231013'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
    implementation 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4'
    implementation 'commons-validator:commons-validator:1.9.0'
    implementation 'ma.glasnost.orika:orika-core:1.5.4'
    implementation 'com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:9.41.2'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    implementation 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:33.3.1-jre'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.34'

    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.8.0'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}


How do you query the DB?

Using PgAdmin tool.

This question is similar to: Spring Data JPA delete native query throwing exception. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You need to specify that your repository method, is modifying data, by using the Modifying annotation.
Also mark the service or repository as Transactional.
@Query(value = """
                INSERT INTO users (id, created_by)
                VALUES (nextval('cons_seq'), :createdBy)
        """, nativeQuery = true)
@Modifying
void create(@Param("createdBy") String createdBy);

Also ensure you have included annotation @EnableJpaRepositories in your Application class.
If you have placed you repository and your entities/model in non-standard location, you will have to state the packages in the annotations properties.
I have managed to get your entity and repository running, with the following surrounding setup.
e.g.:
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication .class, args);
    }

}

Service, demoing alternative persistence implementations:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SomeService {

    private final ProfileRepository profileRepository;

    @Transactional
    public void create(final Profile profile) {
        profileRepository.create(profile.getName());
    }

    public List<User> findAll(String name) {
        return profileRepository.findAllByCreatedBy(name);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save(String name) {
        User user = new User();
        user.setCreatedBy(name);
        profileRepository.save(user);
    }

}

Repository, using alternative save implementations:
@Repository
public interface ProfileRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query(value = """
                    INSERT INTO users (id, created_by)
                    VALUES (nextval('cons_seq'), :createdBy)
            """, nativeQuery = true)
    @Modifying
    void create(@Param("createdBy") String createdBy);

    List<User> findAllByCreatedBy(String name);

}


That said, you could also instantiate a user and persist it through the repository.

I added @Modifying but now I get error org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query `

I added @Transactional but I get error org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching TransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match! 

please include your pom.xml (if you're using maven)

I use Gradle. What I need to add into Gradle config file?

your buid.gradle, especially the part where you're configuring dependencies.

Please see updated post.

Do you have any @Configuration classes, where you define @Bean beans?

No, what I need to add?

please post as much as you can of your code, including your SpringBootApplication class, your Configuration classes - if any, your services.
